# clicking button only once (js)

Tags: jquery, onclick, click

I looked over stackoverflow and other websites, but could not find the answer I am looking for.

I have a button of sorts, and I want users to ONLY be able to click on it once. This is my javascript/jquery triggering the click event. But how can I force it so that it can ONLY be clicked once?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     //var $new_total = $('#gtotal').val();

     $('#a_is_valid').click(function () {
         if ($('#code_promo').val() == 'theCode') {
             $('#gtotal').val($('#gtotal').val() - ($('#gtotal').val() - (($('#gtotal').val() * .75))));
         }
     })
 })
```

Comment: Did these answers help you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function.

```
$('#a_is_valid').one('click', function(){
    if ($('#code_promo').val() == 'theCode')
    {$('#gtotal').val($('#gtotal').val()-($('#gtotal').val()-(($('#gtotal').val()*.75))));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use jquery <kbd>[.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)</kbd>  This will ensure that the click event happens only once.

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qtEHE/)</kbd>

```
$('#a_is_valid').one('click', function(){

        if ($('#code_promo').val() == 'theCode')
        {
          var gtot = $('#gtotal').val();
          $('#gtotal').val(gtot -(gtot -(gtot *.75)));
        }
 });
```

Another way is to use <kbd>[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)</kbd> and <kbd>[off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)</kbd>

```
$('#a_is_valid').on('click', handleClick);

function handleClick() {
    var gtot = $('#gtotal').val();
    $(this).off('click');
    if ($('#code_promo').val() == 'theCode') {
        $('#gtotal').val( gtot - (gtot-(gtot * 0.75)) );
    }
}
```

Comment: is `this` a jQuery object?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of `.click()`?

Comment: I thought I answered back. Weird :/ Yes, in answer to everyone's question, yes they helped :D Thanks!

Sorry I cannot post more for now. I sincerely am thankful for all of your time, guys. Truly. I wish I could say more, but I have to go.

Answer (score 1):

Use modern JS!

```
const button = document.getElementById("a_is_valid");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Add one-time callback
}, {once : true});
```

You could also just disable the button:

```
button.disabled = true;
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/addeventlistener-once), [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=once-event-listener)

Comment: How to make this auto click ?